(exim4) Trigger script when outbound email is delivered/fails
Is it possible to get exim4 to trigger a script after a email is successfully delivered or if it fails/bounces without having to tail and parse the log files? My end goal is to mark addresses in a newsletter as non-existing automatically and to be able to see in real-time how a batch of emails are sent out.

The feature to use is delivery_event_action
https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-events.html
you may need to patch the exim source to add some missing event triggers.
There are a large number of events many of which may be uninteresting.
I use an ${acl ... } expresseion as my event action and in the acl code called by this decide whether I want to record this event or not.
